# app function: authentication to get a workspace?

Tags: azure-functions

In an azure function app, when I do a *ws = Workspace.get(name=..., subscription_id=..., resource_group=...)*, I have the message "Failed to load or parse file /home/.azure/azureProfile.json. It will be overridden by default settings.", followed by "Performing interactive authentication. Please follow the instructions on the terminal... and I have to enter a code in a new browser window. I also tried with this to force authentication:
*auth = InteractiveLoginAuthentication (tenant_id.")
ws = Workspace.get(name=..., subscription_id=..., resource_group=..., auth = auth)*
but it's not better.
Would anyone know how to handle authentication properly?

Thansks for your help.

Comment: Could you please provide your code and describe your need indetail?

Comment: My question is "how to manage the authentication with the azureml.core.Workspace.get method to avoid the messages "Failed to load or parse file /home/.azure/azureProfile.json" and "Performing interactive authentication. Please follow the instructions on the terminal"?"

Comment: Azure function is not an interactive  service. I suggest you use service principal authentication to access workspace : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-setup-authentication#service-principal-authentication

Comment: OK thanks, I still have to understand how the service principal authentication works and how to set it up

Comment: Do you have any update?

Answer (score 1):

Azure function is not an interactive service. So we can not use `InteractiveLoginAuthentication` to finish auth. I suggest you use  service principal authentication or MSI authentication to finish auth

- ***Service Principal Authentication***

1. Create a service principal

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --sdk-auth --name <app name> --skip-assignment
```

[image]

2. Get the object id of the sp

```
az ad sp show --id <the sp clientId> --query objectId
```

[image]

3. Allow the SP to access your Azure Machine Learning workspace

```
az extension add -n azure-cli-ml
az ml workspace share -w your-workspace-name -g your-resource-group-name --user your-sp-object-id --role owner
```

4. code

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
from azureml.core.authentication import ServicePrincipalAuthentication
from azureml.core.workspace import Workspace

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    tenant_id="72f98****d011db47" # tenantID
    service_principal_id="8e23844****3278" # clientId
    service_principal_password="G4YUf9****ZXK-a3npU" # clientSecret
    subscription_id = "b83c1****b83a074c23f"
    resource_group = "v-wenxu-chinacxp"
    workspace_name="test"
    sp = ServicePrincipalAuthentication(tenant_id=tenant_id, # tenantID
                                        service_principal_id=service_principal_id, # clientId
                                        service_principal_password=service_principal_password) # clientSecret

    ws =Workspace.get(name=workspace_name, resource_group=resource_group, subscription_id=subscription_id, auth=sp)
    
    return func.HttpResponse(ws.location)
```

- ***MSI authentication***

1. [Enable MSI for Azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=dotnet#add-a-system-assigned-identity)
2. 3. Allow the MSI to access your Azure Machine Learning workspace

```
az extension add -n azure-cli-ml
az ml workspace share -w your-workspace-name -g your-resource-group-name --user your-MSI-object-id --role owner
```

3. Code

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
from azureml.core.workspace import Workspace
from azureml.core.authentication import MsiAuthentication

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    
    subscription_id = "b83c1****b83a074c23f"
    resource_group = "v-wenxu-chinacxp"
    workspace_name="test"
    msi_auth=MsiAuthentication()

    ws =Workspace.get(name=workspace_name, resource_group=resource_group, subscription_id=subscription_id, auth=msi_auth)
    
    return func.HttpResponse(ws.location)
```

For more details, please refer to [here](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/manage-azureml-service/authentication-in-azureml/authentication-in-azureml.ipynb) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-setup-authentication#service-principal-authentication).

Comment: thank you very much Jim for these detailed explanations